# crop the background image in half

Tags: html, css

I have a block with a background image. And for small screens I need to make it so that this picture is cut off by 50%, and at the same time occupies the entire block

I try to do `background-size: 50% 100%;` but in the end the picture is not cropped, but simply occupies 50% of the entire block

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/e1kYBwm.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .wrapper {
    background-size: 50% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can scale the background horizontally by 200% instead of 50%, which I think is the effect you are looking for.  But if not, can you give some more details and background on what you're trying to achieve, because I'm not certain I understand the whole problem.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://i.imgur.com/e1kYBwm.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 575px) {
  .wrapper {
    background-size: 200% 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```